# Help with recurrence equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I need to solve the following recurrence equation

$p_i =\begin{cases} r(p_{i-1}+p_{i+2}) &\mbox{if } i \text{ is odd} \\ 
(1-r)(p_{i-1}+p_{i}) & \mbox{if } i \text{ is even} \end{cases}  i \in \mathbb{N}$

This equation came up trying to find an invariant measure vector for a given stochastic matrix, in fact $0\leq r \leq 1$.

I have no clue how to solve this, any help will be great :)

Comment: Initial Data ??? i.e. $p_0,p_1$ =?

Comment: There is not initial data, I need to find a general solution of this equation.

Comment: Are indices in $2$nd part right? (if so, then for even $i$ $p_i$ depends on $p_{i-1}$ only: $p_i = \frac{1-r}{r}p_{i-1}$, and is noncorrect for $r=0$).

Comment: There is no problem with the indices, in fact if $r=0$ the equation simplify to $p_i=0$ if $i$ is odd and $p_i= p_{i-1}+ p_i$ if $i$ is even, this second one reduces to $p_{i-1}=0$ which is the same that $p_i=0$ when $i$ is odd.

Comment: If $p_i=p_{i-1}+p_i$, then $p_i$ is undefined for even $i$. I thought it must be $$p_i=r(p_{i-1}+p_{i-2}),~~\mbox{ if }i \mbox{ is odd},$$ $$p_{i}=(1-r)(p_{i-1}+p_{i-2}),~~\mbox{ if }i \mbox{ is even}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If statement is correct:

$$
p_n =\begin{cases} r(p_{n-1}+p_{n+2}) &\mbox{if } n \text{ is odd} \\ 
(1-r)(p_{n-1}+p_{n}) & \mbox{if } n \text{ is even} \end{cases}  n \in \mathbb{N}
$$

then for $r\ne 0$
$$
\Downarrow
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
rp_{n+2} = p_{n} - rp_{n-1}, &\mbox{if } n \text{ is odd} \\ 
rp_{n} = (1-r)p_{n-1} & \mbox{if } n \text{ is even} \end{cases}  n \in \mathbb{N}\tag{1}
$$

$$
\Downarrow
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
rp_{n+2} = p_{n} - (1-r)p_{n-2}, &\mbox{if } n \text{ is odd} \\ 
rp_{n} = (1-r)p_{n-1} & \mbox{if } n \text{ is even} \end{cases}  n \in \mathbb{N}\tag{2}
$$

Now consider only odd $n$: $n=2k-1$.
Search $p_{2k-1}$ in the form 
$$
p_{2k-1} = ab^{k}.
$$
Then $(2) \implies$ 
$$
rab^{k+1} = ab^{k}-(1-r)ab^{k-1},
$$
$$
rb^{2} = b-(1-r),
$$
$$
rb^{2} - b+(1-r)=0,
$$
this quadratic (on $b$) equation has solutions:

$$
b=1,  \qquad b=\dfrac{1-r}{r}.
$$

If $b=1$, then solution of $(1)$ has form
$p_{2k-1}=a, p_{2k}=\dfrac{1-r}{r}a$.

If $b=\dfrac{1-r}{r}$, then
$$
p_{2k-1}=a\left(\dfrac{1-r}{r}\right)^k,
$$
$$
p_{2k}=a\left(\dfrac{1-r}{r}\right)^{k+1}.
$$

$a$ is any real value (if $p_1$ would defined, then $a$ would defined too).

The case $r=0$ is obvious.